# How can I copy a pointer to another class within a class to another pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, copy, private

In other words, how can I take a pointer of a class-type that is within a different class and copy it to another pointer of the same class-type.

**Here's an example:**

```
class Bananas
{
    private:
        int peel;
        string color;
};

class Apples
{
    private:
        Bananas *ptr1;
        Bananas *ptr2;

    public:
        void copyPointers();
};
```

In the above example, I need to copy the values of **ptr1** to **ptr2**.

Note: **ptr2** is empty.

**Failed Attempt #1:**

```
memcpy(ptr2, ptr1, strlen(ptr1)+1);
```

**Failed Attempt #2:**

```
ptr2 = ptr1;
```

**UPDATE:**

To further explain my function:

```
void Apples::copyPointers()
{
    ptr2 = ptr1;
}
```

Comment: post a complete but minimal example that people can try out. also post your diagnostic messages.

Comment: `ptr1` and `ptr2` are private members of `Apples` - so the code in your "Failed Attempt #2" will only work if it appears inside a member function definition - `copyPointers()` is your only member function, so try putting it in there.

Comment: What are you expecting `strlen(ptr1)` to do when `ptr1` isn't a null-terminated char array?

Comment: Using strlen was a mistake for sure, but I have it working now. Does anybody have a way to delete ptr1? I tried using **delete prt1;** but I get an error:
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x081b000c ***

Comment: Was `ptr1` obtained from a call to `new`?

Comment: Yes, in my constuctor I set **ptr1 = new Bananas[2];**

Comment: That's `new[]`, not `new`. You need to use `delete [] ptr1` to delete it. Also in that case, you'd probably be much better off using a `std::vector` if you just need a dynamic array.

Comment: @goatmeal: you must ensure each call to `new[]` matches a single later `delete[]`.  If you copy the pointers around, it's very easy to accidentally call `delete[]` twice on the same pointer value.  Note that the compiler-generated default copy constructor and assignment operator will also make copies of the pointers, so if you call `delete[]` in the destructor then copies of the object may delete the same memory used by the object that was copied.  A container like `std::vector<Bananas>` or `std::list<>`, or `vector<std::unique_ptr>` or `...<std::shared_ptr>` is more reliable.

Comment: What Tony D said. Also if you had done what the first comment says, this would've been solved much faster. Furthermore, had you used a vector in the first place, this error wouldn't even have happened.

Comment: Do you want both pointers to refer to the same Banana? Or do you want the second pointer to refer to a new Banana, a copy of the first Banana?

Comment: I want the second copy to hold the values of the first banana, and then I want to delete the first banana. Afterwards, I want to recreate a larger first banana, and transfer the contents back over.

Comment: In that case, why do you want to delete anything? You can just make `ptr2` point to what `ptr1` used to point to, and then set `ptr1` to `nullptr` to make it clear it's not pointing to anything anymore. No need to copy or delete anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to copy the value of the pointer (the memory address):

```
ptr2 = ptr1;
```

Now `ptr2` will point to the same object as `ptr1`.

If you need to copy the ***object*** that `ptr1` points to, and assign that new object to `ptr2`:

```
ptr2 = new Bananas(*ptr1);
```

This will call the `Bananas` copy constructor with the object pointed to by `ptr1`. Remember to `delete ptr2` afterwards (or use `std::unique_ptr` which does this drudgework for you automatically).

Comment: @goatmeal `delete ptr1;` if it was allocated by `new`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int *ptr1;
    int *ptr2;

    ptr2 = ptr1;
    *ptr1 = 21;
    std::cout << *ptr2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Seems to work fine.
I can't see why `ptr2 = ptr1` wouldn't work.

However, if you create an instance of Bananas, and then dereference it into ptr1, that would assign ptr1 a new value; but ptr2 would still have the old value... Which is pointing to a nothing of type Bananas.

EDIT:
An extended example using structs (classes in disguise):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    int val;    
};

int main() {
    A a;
    A *ptr1;
    A *ptr2;

    ptr2 = ptr1; // ptr1 is nothing, so ptr2 is the same nothing now.

    ptr1 = &a; // ptr1 is now something! But ptr2 is still the old nothing.
    ptr1->val = 21;
    ptr2 = ptr1; // Assign ptr1's something to ptr2's nothing
    std::cout << ptr2->val << std::endl; // ptr2 is now pointing at the same object as ptr1.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's undefined behavior. Neither `ptr1` nor `ptr2` point to valid ints, and you're dereferencing them.

Comment: I'm not suggesting he does this, I'm simply using an example with what I think he's doing wrong; which is copying pointers that don't exist, and expecting them to be bound together forever.

Comment: Oh okay. I misunderstood that.

Comment: @zenith Sorry, in my first example I was just trying to show that assignment works on pointers successfully, although the actions of my code may be UB, you apparently can assign to a dereferenced ptr to an int, but I'm guessing it's not safe.

Comment: Indeed, `*` + uninitialized pointer is never safe, except with `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

So first you need a copy constructor for Banana.

```
class Banana {
  Banana (const Banana& b): peel(b.peel), color(b.color) {}
};
```

then, inside Apple, you build a new banana from the old one

```
Banana* ptr2 = new Banana(*ptr1);
```

It's not clear to me why you are using pointers, but there you go.
If you want to delete the first Banana,

```
delete ptr1;
```